# Trying to install H2O on Databricks. How can I install a 3rd party package in Databricks?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm playing around with Databricks now, and looking at a demo online.  The demo requires H2O to be installed.  In Databricks, I tried the following:

```
   click clusters (then click on the name of the cluster)
   click libraries
   click install new
   finally, click maven
```

In the coordinates box, I paste the following:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages ai.h2o:sparkling-water-package_2.12:3.30.0.6-1-3.0
```

I am following the instructions from the links below.

https://docs.databricks.com/applications/machine-learning/third-party/index.html

http://docs.h2o.ai/sparkling-water/3.0/latest-stable/doc/install/install_and_start.html#sparkling-water-as-a-spark-package

How can I install a 3rd party package in Databricks?  Thanks!